# MVC actions with generic parameter names AND specific names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, overloading

I would like to have a method that takes either specific parameter names, or generic ones:

```
    //generic
    public ActionResult Delete(string param1, string param2, int param3)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    //specific
    public ActionResult Delete(string sAssetCode, string sLockout, int Seq)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

The generic method naming allows me to setup routes like the below one, which allows me to easily create a URL to delete objects via almost any controller:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AssetLockoutDelete",
            url: "{controller}/Delete/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
            defaults: new { action = "Delete" }
        );
```

But this means that the methods are a little harder to read and follow, as the parameters are generic now.

**How can I have both methods exist in my controller while still being elegant?**

One possibility is the following, but it seems not as elegent:

```
    //generic
    public ActionResult Delete_Helper(string param1, string param2, int param3)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    //specific
    public ActionResult Delete(string sAssetCode, string sLockout, int Seq)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

     //redirects all deletes to the "helper" method that uses generic parameter names
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "AssetLockoutDelete",
         url: "{controller}/Delete/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
         defaults: new { action = "Delete_Helper" }
     );
```

Comment: There is nothing elegant about url: "{controller}/Delete/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}", How does one know if they need one two or all of the params to successfully delete their item on a particular controller? Trial and error?

Comment: @PaulSwetz if the parameter is null then its not needed